# How to conditionally add array-items to another array of items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, lookup, reduce

I want to add items from one array to another array. I have a solution but to be honest I wonder if it is scalable at all. I make two database queries. Currently there are not many items, but there might be a lot of items, and then I don't know whether the solution is still suitable.

**Is there a resource-saving solution?

```js
const brands = [
{"id":1,"name":"brand_1","img_name":""},
{"id":2,"name":"brand_2","img_name":""},
{"id":4,"name":"brand_3","img_name":""},
{"id":3,"name":"brand_4","img_name":""}];

const models = [{"id":1,"name":"model_2","img_name":"","brand_id":2},{"id":2,"name":"model_1","img_name":"","brand_id":2},{"id":3,"name":"model_2","img_name":"","brand_id":2},{"id":4,"name":"model_2","img_name":"","brand_id":2},{"id":5,"name":"model_2","img_name":"","brand_id":2},{"id":6,"name":"model_2","img_name":"","brand_id":2},{"id":7,"name":"model_2","img_name":"","brand_id":2},{"id":8,"name":"model_2","img_name":"","brand_id":2}];


models.forEach(e => {
  brands.forEach(a => {
    if (! a.models) {
      a.models = [];
    }
    if (a.id === e.brand_id) {
      a.models.push(e)
    }
    })
})

console.log(brands);
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. The only thing you can do is make it shorter, which may sacrifice some readability.

Comment: @caTS ... of cause, and as the OP already did expect, it is not optimized due to the two nested `forEach` iterations. A performance optimized approach for a vast amount of `brands` and `models` data would choose a lookup based approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the target structure is derived from the `brands` array and its items, one needs to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) this array once.

In order to not to introduce another nested iteration one would want to create and assign a new `brand` item's `model` array from a lookup-table which holds the latter as references of a grouping key where the key equals both a `brand` item's `id`-value and a `model` item's `brand_id`-value.

The lookup will be created by a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task which iterates the `models` array once.

Thus the above described and beneath implemented approach prevents nested array iterations.

```js
const brands = [
  { id: 1, name: "brand_1", img_name: "" },
  { id: 2, name: "brand_2", img_name: "" },
  { id: 3, name: "brand_3", img_name: "" },
  { id: 4, name: "brand_4", img_name: "" },
];
const models = [
  { id: 1, name: "model_1", img_name: "", brand_id: 2 },
  { id: 2, name: "model_2", img_name: "", brand_id: 2 },
  { id: 3, name: "model_3", img_name: "", brand_id: 2 },
  { id: 4, name: "model_4", img_name: "", brand_id: 2 },
  { id: 5, name: "model_5", img_name: "", brand_id: 2 },

  { id: 1, name: "model_1", img_name: "", brand_id: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: "model_2", img_name: "", brand_id: 1 },

  { id: 1, name: "model_1", img_name: "", brand_id: 4 },
];

// create an object based model lookup
// where each model gets collected in
// an array which is grouped by the
// model's `brand_id` property value.
const modelsByBrandId = models
  .reduce((lookup, model) => {

    // access or create the grouped model array.
    (lookup[model.brand_id] ??= []).push(model);

    return lookup;

  }, {});

console.log({ modelsByBrandId });

// map the `brands` array by creating each
// a new (and decoupled from the original
// reference) brand item where the brand-
// `id` related `models` array gets picked
// from the mapper function's bound lookup.
const result = brands
  .map(function assignModelsFromBoundLookup(brand) {
    const lookup = this;

    // create a new brand item which is
    // decoupled from its passed reference.
    return {
      ...brand,
      models: (brand.models ?? [])
        .concat(lookup[brand.id] ?? []),
    };
  }, modelsByBrandId);

console.log({ result });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

I personally recommend a final code iteration where one implements both the mapper and the reducer function as function statements.

It contributes to a better readability, code-reuse and performance too.

```js
// create and programmatically build an object based model lookup
// where each model gets collected in an array which is grouped
// by the model's `brand_id` property value.
function collectItemIntoBrandIdGroupedModels(lookup, model) {

  // access or create the grouped model array.
  (lookup[model.brand_id] ??= []).push(model);

  return lookup;
}

// create a new (and decoupled from the original reference)
// brand item where the brand-`id` related `models` array
// gets picked from the mapper function's bound lookup.
function assignModelsFromBoundLookup(brand) {
  const lookup = this;

  // create new brand item.
  return {
    ...brand,
    models: (brand.models ?? [])
      .concat(lookup[brand.id] ?? []),
  };
}

const brands = [
  { id: 1, name: "brand_1", img_name: "" },
  { id: 2, name: "brand_2", img_name: "" },
  { id: 3, name: "brand_3", img_name: "" },
  { id: 4, name: "brand_4", img_name: "" },
];
const models = [
  { id: 1, name: "model_1", img_name: "", brand_id: 2 },
  { id: 2, name: "model_2", img_name: "", brand_id: 2 },
  { id: 3, name: "model_3", img_name: "", brand_id: 2 },
  { id: 4, name: "model_4", img_name: "", brand_id: 2 },
  { id: 5, name: "model_5", img_name: "", brand_id: 2 },

  { id: 1, name: "model_1", img_name: "", brand_id: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: "model_2", img_name: "", brand_id: 1 },

  { id: 1, name: "model_1", img_name: "", brand_id: 4 },
];

const result = brands
  .map(
    assignModelsFromBoundLookup,
    models
      .reduce(collectItemIntoBrandIdGroupedModels, {}),
  );

console.log({ result });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you Peter! The first variant is understandable and looks manageable. I wonder whether it really promises a performance advantage. I would have to test that. The second variant looks more demanding but I think it is the better variant of the two. I completely agree with you there. Do you already have this variant in production? Thank you for your time and effort! It is a nice answer!

Comment: @MaxPattern ... _"The second variant looks more demanding"_ ... The 2nd variant is technically the same as the 1st one. It just uses function references as callbacks, and thus, in my opinion, makes the 2nd variant more expressive / readable / maintainable. I also follow and advocate the approach of referring to precisely named function statements for years which results in a lot of enterprise code written over the last one and a half decade.

Comment: Thank you very much for the good explanation and answearing of my comment!